# Center content with twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a login screen where there is a login box that I'd like to appear in the center of the screen (horizontally and vertically) no matter what resolution the user has.

I have looked around and can only find tutorials/articles that center content horizontally, which is half of what I want.

Any idea how I can achieve centralisation in both planes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best approach is using CSS and a Javascript callback for older IE versions.

#### CSS

```
.center {
   width: 300px;          // your login div width
   height: 300px;         // your login box height
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%; 
   margin-left: -150px;   // width/2
   margin-top: -150px;    // height/2
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="center">
    Hey dude, I'm in the middle!
</div>
```

#### Live example

http://jsfiddle.net/86Asb/

Negative margins are exactly half the height and width, which pull the element back into perfect center. Only works with elements of a fixed height/width. This will work in all browsers except IE6,IE7 maybe.

Comment: Thanks, the CSS way is lighter weight and updates on window resize (the JS version could do that but it's more code).

Comment: how would you center with position absolute if a box isnt of a specified width? for example i need to center a title which can be short or long

Comment: @Marko: that was actually a test for a job interview I had: Use `left:50%; top:50%;` then the problem is that you need to know the width to set `margin-left: -width/2` and `margin-top: -height/2` ;)

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know to vertically center an item is using javascript. Here is a simple example of how to do it using jquery and absolute positioning through CSS. Link to a jsfiddle and code to follow.

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienHoboken/XCPGe

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var width = $('#test').css('width');
  var height = $('#test').css('height');
  width = width.replace('px', '');
  height = height.replace('px', '');
  $('#test').css('left', ($(window).width()/2) - (width/2));
  $('#test').css('top', ($(window).height()/2) - (height/2));
});
```

CSS:

```
#test {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000000;
}
```

Comment: That's because it was using screen height. But I made some updates, see if it works for you now.

Comment: @AlienHoboken +1 because it does work but I the CSS answer is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following solution (no fixed width of dialog), keeps it centered horizontally.

```
#test {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 300px;
  left: 1%;
  right: 1%;
}
```

Any feedback / disadvantages appreciated!